# Java : Multithreading -Wait/notifyAll Question

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

I have a class which spawns a bunch of threads and have to wait till all the spawned threads are completed. ( I need to calculate the time for all threads to complete).

The MainClass spawns all the threads and then it checks whether all the threads are completed before it can call itself completed.

Will this logic work. If so, is there a better way to do this? If not , I would like to better understand this scenario.

```
class MainClass{
    private boolean isCompleted;
    ...
    for(task : tasks){
        threadpool.execute(task);
    }

    for(task : tasks){
        if(!task.isCompleted()){
            task.wait()
        }
    }

    isCompleted = true;
}


class Task{
    public void run(){
        ....
        ....
        synchronized(this){
            task.completed = true;
            notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your code doesn't work because your forgot a `synchronized` block around `wait()`. See my answer for a better (faster) solution.

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking for. I need atleast 5 minutes. Before I can close this. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`notifyAll()` is relatively slow. A better way is to use `CountDownLatch`:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

int n = 10;
CountDownLatch doneSignal = new CountDownLatch(n);
// ... start threads ...
doneSignal.await();

// and within each thread:
doWork();
doneSignal.countDown();
```

Comment: +1, although you didn't explain why `CountDownLatch` would be a better option, other than arbitrarily (and implicitly) saying that it's faster than a wait-notify scheme.

Comment: I do have one question. If the count down never reaches 0. will the thread hang?

Comment: @Vanchinathan Chandrasekaran Yes.

Answer (score 4):

There's no need for wait/notify in this case. You can just loop through the threads and call `join()`. If the thread's already finished, the MainClass thread will just wait for the next one.

You might want to have a look at the higher-level utilities in the `java.util.concurrent` package too.

Comment: +1, for mentioning simple solution (i.e. `Thread.join()`) and for referring to the `java.util.concurrent` package as a better alternative.

Answer (score 4):

All this can be done by java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService.

```
class MainClass {
    ...
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    List<Callable> tasks = ...; // prepare your tasks

    // this invokes all tasks in parallel and waits until all are done
    executor.invokeAll(tasks);
    ...
}
```

That's about it.

Comment: I've just tried that and program was runnig a while after `invokeAll`. I found that you have to call `executor.shutdown();` which releases all threads and program can end immediately.